# geometry nodes: randomly select a single face from a mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to select a single face of a mesh.

[image]

What is shown in the picture is then connected to a separate geometry node.

Sometimes I get nothing and sometimes even a few faces. I tried setting *Max* to the exact number of faces, but this only works if there are a lot of faces (I guess that causes the chances for a failure to be so low that it appears to work). If I have a subdivided plane with 4 faces, I set *Max* to 4 or 3 (I don't know if it starts with 0 or 1, I tried everything) but nothing gets selected.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Looks OK, _so far_ . Can you show us how your 'Result' Boolean is being used?

Comment: The index always starts with 0. Please show us the whole node tree, or share your blend file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use an *Integer* input node (a constant) as the *ID*, and set the value for *Max* to point count - 1 (or the last index, so if 10 point = 9). That will give you a single random value.

Here are two examples:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I couldn't find info on how to select random faces on a multi-subdivided plane, only this thread.